# Eclipse build path: library with native library folder

Tags: eclipse, dozer, buildpath, supercsv

I created an Eclipse project and I need to use the Super CSV library with Dozer. I downloaded the Super CSV and created a new folder "super-csv" in /usr/lib.

Now I have: `/usr/lib/super-csv/super-csv` that contains the super csv jar (+ javadoc and source), 
`/usr/lib/super-csv/super-csv-dozer` that contains the super csv dozer jar, javadoc and source plus a "lib" folder.

Inside `/usr/lib/super-csv/super-csv-dozer/lib` there are many .jar files that are needed for super-csv-dozer to work, so I added it as native library for super-csv-dozer entry in library tab of java build path in Eclipse.

When I try to compile the project, I receive a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` pointing a class that is contained in one of the jar files in the lib folder.

Everything works only if I manually add every jar in lib folder as an external jar.

Can someone explain me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html) - it's a widely used tool for Java builds. To start using Super CSV, it would be as simple as adding the 2 dependencies (listed on the Super CSV [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/downloading.html)), and your Eclipse project would be ready to go.

There's a bit of a learning curve though, so if you want to just add the jars to Eclipse's build path manually, I'd recommend creating a `lib` directory at the root of your project and putting all of the jars there.

```
my-project
    |-src
    |  |- (your source in here)
    |
    |-lib
       |-commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
       |-commons-lang-2.5.jar
       |-commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
       |-dozer-5.3.2.jar
       |-slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
       |-super-csv-2.0.1.jar
       |-super-csv-dozer-2.0.1.jar
```

You can then add them to the build path ([here's](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) a good guide).

Just a note: if you're not using the Dozer extension, then you'll only need `super-csv-2.0.1.jar` on the build path.

Comment: Maven is not "the" industry standard, it is "an" industry standard. Don't have tunnel vision.

Comment: Fair enough - my point was that it's a good idea to use a build tool, and (for Java) Maven is a good place to start being the [most widely used](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-build-tools-part-2-a-decision-makers-comparison-of-maven-gradle-and-ant-ivy/). Yet there's people out there still using Ant, and lots who have moved to Gradle (me included), so I've happily edited this answer.